# how can one make seaborn clustermap cluster rows and cols jointly

Tags: cluster-analysis, seaborn

How can one constrain the rows and cols clustering to be the same (e.g. for finding groups in a pair-wise matrix).
In the docs you can turn row or col clustering on/off but it's independent of each other.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like per-computing the linkage and then feed it into both the rows and columns works. Since my D matrix is symmetric the linkage will be identical for both rows and columns.
This can be accomplished with the following code:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
link = linkage(D) # D being the measurement
seaborn.clustermap(D, row_linkage=link, col_linkage=link)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged; would you mind explaining what you're doing so future readers can more easily understand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can first calculate the correlation matrix upon D and then plot the clustermap.

```
corr_df=D.corr()
seaborn.clustermap(corr_df.as_matrix())
```